# Why is it not recommended to define maven artifact repository URL in pom file? (Azure context, artifact source)

Tags: maven, azure

My team is migrating our code to an Azure environment and Microsoft's own article on the subject describes how to use Maven in an Azure environment:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/labs/mavenpmvsts/?view=vsts

One of Maven's best practices is to avoid defining repository elements within the pom file and use a repository manager configured within the settings.xml instead.

The Microsoft article instructs otherwise: they say to add the repository url right in the pom file.

I would have been okay with it if the repository element was defined only in the distributionManagement section, but that is not the case. The article defines the url in a repositories element outside of the distribution context.

My understanding of the repository element of the pom.xml file is that it overrides the source of artifacts used for fetching dependencies. The problem I see defining this in the pom file is that it could have adverse effects depending how the library is being reused.

Use case example:
1) Shared library is created with repository url defined in pom
2) Shared library is deployed.   POM file containing url and JAR file are published.
3) Artifact repository is moved, renamed or copied, url is changed.
4) Later on, a new application using that shared library is created, but uses the new repository url. The URL in the application pom is now different from the one in the shared library's previously published pom.

Because Maven uses a dependency graph and inheritance, what I would expect to happen is that when we build the new application:

1) maven will read the application pom file and begin exploring the dependency graph by downloading pom files for each of the application's dependencies from the URL found in the application's pom. In this case, the only download is the shared library's pom.

2) maven will explore transitive dependencies and read the shared library's pom. Reading the shared library's pom, the repository section will take precedence over the application's pom in the context of the shared library's dependencies.   The shared library's dependencies poms would be downloaded from the old URL.

3) maven will continue like that and download all the pom files until the dependency tree has been built.

4) depending on project configuration, maven will go through the graph it built to download the jars and etc using the same rules.

In this use case, maven would download artifacts from both the old source and the new source. If the old source no longer exists or isn't accessible in this build context, the project cannot be built. This is why it's best to avoid setting repository urls in a pom file.

Or so I thought.

I wrote a scripted demo with local repositories to show my team exactly what would happen and to my surprise, even though Maven does download the shared library's pom file containing a different repository url, the repository tag does not seem to be overriding the one from the application being built. Logs show all artifacts being downloaded from the source specified in the "top" application pom.

So my question to Stack Overflow is two fold:

1) Why am I wrong?   Did I misunderstand Maven's inheritance, dependency graph building and behavior?

2) Shouldn't Maven download the shared library's dependencies from the url specified in the repository tag, if specified? I'm sure there are some cases where the artifacts must come from a private repo. (ex: org.geotools)

3) Does anyone have experience setting up Maven on Azure? Did you follow Microsoft's guide or found a way to move repository urls to your settings.xml in an Azure environment?